# AUCTEX won't create dsc file

Tags: latex, auctex, preview-latex

I'm using Emacs24 on windows with AUCTEX for Latex.
When I try to toggle preview it doesn't show, insteed there is a little "not working" picture on each equation and I get an error

> Running `Preview-PDF2DSC' with ``pdf2dsc "*region*".pdf
>   "*region*.prv/tmp9244b3d"/preview.dsc''
>   Files\gs\gs8.71\bin\gswin32.exe/==/ was unexpected at this time.
>
> Preview-PDF2DSC exited abnormally with code 255 at Wed Sep  6 14:30:04
>   PDF2DSC sentinel: Opening input file: No such file or directory,
>   c:/Users/menis/Dropbox/master/LaTex/*region*.prv/tmp9244b3d/preview.dsc

Note: I checked and Emacs is able to read PNG files.
Also Latex-preview-pane is working properly so I guess ghostscript and doc-view are also working fine.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Can you update your Ghostscript to 9.21 and try it again?

Comment: @ArashEsbati I updated and got the same error :   
TeX Output exited as expected with code 1 at Thu Sep  7 08:47:51
Running `Preview-PDF2DSC' with ``pdf2dsc "_region_".pdf "_region_.prv/tmp9052H2N"/preview.dsc''
Files\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin64.exe/==/ was unexpected at this time.

Preview-PDF2DSC exited abnormally with code 255 at Thu Sep  7 08:47:51
PDF2DSC sentinel: Opening input file: No such file or directory, c:/Users/menis/Dropbox/master/LaTex/_region_.prv/tmp9052H2N/preview.dsc

Comment: I experienced the same error message, but it turned out that the LaTeX code itself had a mistake: I did a \begin{equation} and forgot the \end{equation}. You should try to compile your code, and the compiler will help you find the error. Alternatively, preview over smaller and smaller regions until you isolate the typo.